# Webtoon where the main character wakes up as a villainess in a novel and becomes close friends with the female lead of the novel

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

I'm looking for a webtoon, where the main character (mc) dies and is sent into the world of a novel, where she wakes up as a child. She knows she is the villain and wishes to change her fate.

She becomes close friends with the female lead and the male lead is brought to her home (I honestly cannot remember how he got there.)
I do remember that the original female lead's (og fl's) older brother comes back into town from school and the ml becomes jealous, because the og fl wants the mc and her brother to marry and he wants to be with the mc.

Another thing I remember is a scene where they are at a festival and get separated from everyone else, then attacked by a demon; she some how bonds with said demon and it becomes a cute squirrel.

I can't remember the name or if this was just some random fever dream I have had.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is *[You've Got the Wrong Girl](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/youve-got-the-wrong-girl)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/youve-got-the-wrong-girl/info).

> Evelyn Monstera knows two things. First, she's been **reborn as a mean girl in a fantasy novel**, and second, if nothing changes, her cruelty to the main characters will be her undoing. So **when the male lead of the novel, Casis Urquio, comes to stay at her manor**, all she has to do is stay out of his way. Unfortunately, Evelyn not only causes a fight between the protagonists, but also wins the affection of the male lead too! Can Evelyn set the story straight and get the happily ever after she wants?

The synopsis covers half the details of the question; the protagonist transmigrates to the world of a novel as the villainess. The male lead comes to stay at her family's manor to recover from an illness.

She is close friends with the female lead of the original story. In the original story, the two started as friends but drifted apart due to Evelyn's love for the ML. In the manhwa they stay friends. The OGFL does explicitly want her brother to marry the protagonist.

[image: Marriage to become family]

The scene with the demonic beast is in Chapter 18. At a festival, Evelyn gets lost and approached by a rabbit; the rabbit is actually a demon. When the ML comes to find her it turns into a beast, but a protective charm forces it back to looking like a rabbit, and allows Evelyn to issue commands.

[image: Beast rabbit]